# how to convert pdf file into xml file in C# .net?

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

I need to convert the pdf file into xml file and save after browsing the pdf file.Right now I am saving it as pdf file using the following code:

```
if(FileUpload.HasFile)
{
    FileUpload.SaveAs(@"D:\MYDOCS\" + FileUpload.FileName);
    Label1.Text = "file uploaded" + FileUpload.FileName;
}
else
{
    Label1.Text = "No File Uploaded.";
}
```

pleae help me out..
or in general please let me know hoe to convert a pdf file in to xml file.

Thanks in Advance...
Reddy

Comment: What schema do you want for your target XML? How should it look? What if the PDF contains images and no text?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box in ASP.NET. Maybe do some research into; http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx